# Sigsegv error after installing node.js, express and edge. Mismatch of versions of modules?

Tags: node.js, express, edge.js

I'm a newbie, and I installed the following successfully on MacOS Yosemite version 10.10.4

1. node.js v0.12.2
2. edge@0.10.0
3. edge-sql@0.1.0
4. express@4.12.3

When I installed Node and express, everything worked at that step
When I installed edge, i followed tjanczuk's installation steps on his website https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge
I didn't get any errors.

When I now try to run my app

```
var express = require('express');
var edge = require('edge');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

var getProducts = edge.func('sql', function() {
    /*select * from Products*/
});

var getProductByID = edge.func('sql', function() {
    /*select * from Products
    where ProductID = @productID */
});

var app = express();

app.get('/products',function(req,res){
    getProducts(null, function (error, result){
        if (error) throw error;
        res.json(result);
    });
});

app.get('products/:productId', function(req,res){
getProductByID({ productID: req.params.productID},function (error, result){
        if (error) throw error;
        res.json(result);
    });
});

app.listen(process.env.port || 3000);

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/favicon.ico'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

I get a sigsegv error

```
(lldb) command source -s 1 '/tmp/mono-gdb-commands.HVRhGm'
Process 70604 stopped
* thread #1: tid = 0x2f296, 0x00007fff8b91d902 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4 + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  thread #2: tid = 0x2f297, 0x00007fff8b91851a libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10, name = 'OptimizingCompi'
  thread #3: tid = 0x2f298, 0x00007fff8b91851a libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10, name = 'v8:SweeperThrea'
  thread #4: tid = 0x2f299, 0x00007fff8b91851a libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10, name = 'v8:SweeperThrea'
  thread #5: tid = 0x2f29a, 0x00007fff8b91851a libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10, name = 'v8:SweeperThrea'
  thread #6: tid = 0x2f29b, 0x00007fff8b91d3fa libsystem_kernel.dylib`__select + 10
  thread #7: tid = 0x2f29d, 0x00007fff8b91851a libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10
* thread #1: tid = 0x2f296, 0x00007fff8b91d902 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4 + 10, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = signal SIGSTOP
  * frame #0: 0x00007fff8b91d902 libsystem_kernel.dylib`__wait4 + 10
    frame #1: 0x0000000102bd8d16 libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib`mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 474
    frame #2: 0x0000000102c2f004 libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib`mono_arch_handle_altstack_exception + 87
    frame #3: 0x0000000102b5053e libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib`mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 375
    frame #4: 0x00007fff89540f1a libsystem_platform.dylib`_sigtramp + 26
    frame #5: 0x0000000102c3b7ba libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib`mono_assembly_get_image + 5
    frame #6: 0x00000001017be50a edge.node`ClrFunc::Initialize(args=0x00007fff5fbff2e8) + 596 at clrfunc.cpp:95
    frame #7: 0x000000010014159f node`v8::internal::FunctionCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&)) + 159
    frame #8: 0x0000000100163caa node`v8::internal::Builtin_HandleApiCall(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) + 538
    frame #9: 0x0000221db52060a2
    frame #10: 0x0000221db5340c13
    frame #11: 0x0000221db52a84f0
    frame #12: 0x0000221db5224ac6
    frame #13: 0x0000221db52a7306
    frame #14: 0x0000221db52a17ec
    frame #15: 0x0000221db529df80
    frame #16: 0x0000221db5294a45
    frame #17: 0x0000221db5294404
    frame #18: 0x0000221db526b35f
    frame #19: 0x0000221db5269d50
    frame #20: 0x0000221db521ef40
    frame #21: 0x0000221db521de90
    frame #22: 0x00000001002175f3 node`v8::internal::Invoke(bool, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>, int, v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Object>*) + 419
    frame #23: 0x000000010012ad5f node`v8::Function::Call(v8::Handle<v8::Value>, int, v8::Handle<v8::Value>*) + 207
    frame #24: 0x0000000100548de3 node`node::LoadEnvironment(node::Environment*) + 517
    frame #25: 0x000000010054a037 node`node::Start(int, char**) + 305
    frame #26: 0x0000000100000e74 node`start + 52

  thread #2: tid = 0x2f297, 0x00007fff8b91851a libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10, name = 'OptimizingCompi'
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8b91851a libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x00000001006c6277 node`v8::base::Semaphore::Wait() + 23
    frame #2: 0x00000001003feb95 node`v8::internal::OptimizingCompilerThread::Run() + 101
    frame #3: 0x00000001006c7c97 node`v8::base::ThreadEntry(void*) + 87
    frame #4: 0x00007fff8c268268 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 131
    frame #5: 0x00007fff8c2681e5 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 176
    frame #6: 0x00007fff8c26641d libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13

  thread #3: tid = 0x2f298, 0x00007fff8b91851a libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10, name = 'v8:SweeperThrea'
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8b91851a libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x00000001006c6277 node`v8::base::Semaphore::Wait() + 23
    frame #2: 0x00000001002e7217 node`v8::internal::SweeperThread::Run() + 39
    frame #3: 0x00000001006c7c97 node`v8::base::ThreadEntry(void*) + 87
    frame #4: 0x00007fff8c268268 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 131
    frame #5: 0x00007fff8c2681e5 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 176
    frame #6: 0x00007fff8c26641d libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13

  thread #4: tid = 0x2f299, 0x00007fff8b91851a libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10, name = 'v8:SweeperThrea'
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8b91851a libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x00000001006c6277 node`v8::base::Semaphore::Wait() + 23
    frame #2: 0x00000001002e7217 node`v8::internal::SweeperThread::Run() + 39
    frame #3: 0x00000001006c7c97 node`v8::base::ThreadEntry(void*) + 87
    frame #4: 0x00007fff8c268268 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 131
    frame #5: 0x00007fff8c2681e5 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 176
    frame #6: 0x00007fff8c26641d libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13

  thread #5: tid = 0x2f29a, 0x00007fff8b91851a libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10, name = 'v8:SweeperThrea'
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8b91851a libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x00000001006c6277 node`v8::base::Semaphore::Wait() + 23
    frame #2: 0x00000001002e7217 node`v8::internal::SweeperThread::Run() + 39
    frame #3: 0x00000001006c7c97 node`v8::base::ThreadEntry(void*) + 87
    frame #4: 0x00007fff8c268268 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 131
    frame #5: 0x00007fff8c2681e5 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 176
    frame #6: 0x00007fff8c26641d libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13

  thread #6: tid = 0x2f29b, 0x00007fff8b91d3fa libsystem_kernel.dylib`__select + 10
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8b91d3fa libsystem_kernel.dylib`__select + 10
    frame #1: 0x000000010065d073 node`uv__stream_osx_select + 321
    frame #2: 0x000000010065eff0 node`uv__thread_start + 25
    frame #3: 0x00007fff8c268268 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 131
    frame #4: 0x00007fff8c2681e5 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 176
    frame #5: 0x00007fff8c26641d libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13

  thread #7: tid = 0x2f29d, 0x00007fff8b91851a libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10
    frame #0: 0x00007fff8b91851a libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap + 10
    frame #1: 0x0000000102d12f85 libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib`mono_sem_wait + 20
    frame #2: 0x0000000102ccf5fa libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib`finalizer_thread + 83
    frame #3: 0x0000000102cb223d libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib`start_wrapper + 380
    frame #4: 0x0000000102d17c52 libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib`inner_start_thread + 210
    frame #5: 0x0000000102d32ffb libmonoboehm-2.0.1.dylib`GC_start_routine + 83
    frame #6: 0x00007fff8c268268 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 131
    frame #7: 0x00007fff8c2681e5 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 176
    frame #8: 0x00007fff8c26641d libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 13

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Short Analysis: It seems to Crash [here](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge/blame/v0.10.0/src/mono/clrfunc.cpp#L95) - probably when the edge-sql/edge statement is compiled - which seems to be the mono on-demand compilation of your sql code. There is a similar [bug report](https://github.com/tjanczuk/edge/issues/150) . Are you trying to connect to an SQLServer? In this case, it seems that this has less todo with your setup and more with mono and .NET incompatibility. I can't verify that thought.